# How to make something variable something constant?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable list in flutter that won't change anymore once called. The question is: can I make this list constant?
Here is the code:

```
final number = new List<int>.generate(300, (i) => i + 1);

var rng = new Random();
final place = new List.generate(300, (_) => rng.nextInt(3));

final noteListStart = new List<Note>.generate(number.length, (i) => Note(number[i],place[i]));


final List<Note> noteListEnd = [
Note(300, -1), Note(301, -1),Note(302, -1),Note(303, -1)
];

final initList = List<Note>.from(noteListStart)..addAll(noteListEnd);



List<Note> initNotes1() {
  return
    initList;
}
```

In the example above, initNotes1() needs to be constant after being called so I can use it easely somewhere else in the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The thing is that need to use initList anywhere else in the code and that it needs to be constant.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad You can't make a constant out of one of `List`'s factory methods. That code wouldn't compile.

Comment: @FlutterMaster Are you sure you mean "constant"? It sounds like you are asking for your list to become _global_.

Comment: @Abion47 I should have used `final` instead of `const`, that too would work as a global variable. This would work `final number = List.unmodifiable(List<int>.generate(300, (i) => i + 1));`

Answer (score 1):

At this point, it is unclear what your actual question is.

Taken at face value, you are asking how you can compute a list at runtime and then, once the list is populated, convert it into a constant. Well the answer is this: you can't.

Constants are explicit values that are defined before the program has even compiled. By definition, you cannot create a constant from a computed or generated value (unless it is evaluated from simple expressions involving other values are themselves constant). This means you can't create a constant list full of random values - it is antithetical to the whole concent of what a "constant" is.

*(Note: This explanation is a bit specific to Dart, but it is also common among compiled languages. This is different to the definition of a "constant" for an interpreted language such as Javascript, which uses the `const` keyword to merely refer to an immutable variable.)*

If you didn't mean "constant" and merely meant "immutable", then you would mark your list as `final` which would achieve the same thing. As an extra added measure, you can create the list using `List.unmodifiable` to make it so its elements couldn't be changed either.

```dart
final rng = Random();

final _noteListStart = List.generate(startLength, (i) => Note(i + 1, rng.nextInt(3)));
final _noteListEnd = [
  Note(300, -1), Note(301, -1),Note(302, -1),Note(303, -1)
];

List<Note> noteList = List.unmodifiable([..._noteListStart, ..._noteListEnd]);
```

---

However, what it appears you are asking is not how to make a variable *constant*, but instead how to make a variable *global*. This is a question that is both easier and harder to answer.

It's easier because doing so is quite simple. Take the above code, rearrange it a bit, and put it into its own dart file which you can then import and use wherever you wanted:

```dart
// notes_list.dart

final _noteListEnd = [
  Note(300, -1), Note(301, -1),Note(302, -1),Note(303, -1)
];

List<Note> _initList(int startLength) {
  final rng = Random();
  final _noteListStart = List.generate(startLength, (i) => Note(i + 1, rng.nextInt(3)));
  return List.unmodifiable([..._noteListStart, ..._noteListEnd]);
}

final List<Note> noteList = _initList(300);

// other_file.dart

import '/path/to/notes_list.dart';

void main() {
  print(noteList);
}
```

*(Note: The import is mandatory - you cannot make anything _truly_ global in Dart and eliminate the need to import it.)*

On the flip side, this question is harder to answer because the practice of making global variables is frowned upon by many programmers. It belongs to a class of practices that leads to tightly coupled and difficult-to-test code which in turn results in programs that are near impossible to maintain and evolve. In many cases, global variables can be replaced entirely by another practice, such as [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).